# Typescript let keyword and not defined type variable difference

Tags: typescript

I am new to typescript, I know the difference between let and var. But I am not able to understand for what variables we use the 'let' keyword and for what we dont.

In the code here

```
class ClassName{
   let num: number = 10; // Error "A Constructor, method, accessor or property expected"
   num = 10; //Works fine
}

varName: ClassName = new ClassName() // Error "Cannot assign to ClassName because it is not a variable"
let varName: ClassName = new ClassName() // Works fine
```

So we should use let outside classes and should'nt use inside the classes? why if so?

or there is another important difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the inline explanations for your confusions:

```js
class ClassName {
  // In a class scope you can just able to declare its member only
  // which means you can't declare a variable starting with `var/let/const` here
  // Each member can only start with visibility keyword `public/private/protected/static`
  // default is `public`, that's why `num = 10` works fine
}
```

`varName: ClassName = new ClassName()` is all about wrong syntax since `varName` is not a valid keyword.

`let varName: ClassName = new ClassName()` of course is valid syntax saying variable of `varName` is assigned an instance of `ClassName` with the same type `ClassName`.